# Struct marshal in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, interop, struct, marshalling

I have the following struct in C#

```
unsafe public struct control
    {
        public int bSetComPort;
        public int iComPortIndex;
        public int iBaudRate;
        public int iManufactoryID;
        public byte btAddressOfCamera;
        public int iCameraParam;
        public byte PresetNum;
        public byte PresetWaitTime;
        public byte Group;
        public byte AutoCruiseStatus;
        public byte Channel;
        public fixed byte Data[64];
    }
```

And the function i use to convert it to byte array[] is

```
 static byte[] structtobyte(object obj)
    {
        int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
        byte[] arr = new byte[len];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return arr;
    }
```

When i compile it gives

```
Type 'System.Byte[]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.
```

What can be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works fine, the problem must be somewhere else, most likely you're trying to convert another type.

Comment: i`m converting my struct, the problem is the byte array in the struct.

Comment: It's not. I have tried your code and it works fine the way you posted it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: Why is the byte array fixed in the struct, you want a fixed relative position and not an absolute one. It is still a reference and not bytes, since struct does not know size of array at compile time. Also, shouldn't it have a MarshalAsAttribute on it?

Answer (score 4):

`SizeOf` doesn't work on arrays. Use `array.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(elementType)` instead.

Comment: That is! I am was long gusssed, why it gives me wrong size of my structure object — so the reason was that the structure had an arrays in it… ⁺¹

Answer (score 0):

The error you are reporting as a compile error is in fact a runtime error (an `ArgumentException`). When you want to use `structtobyte` to convert a `control` to `byte[]` you should pass the method a reference to `control`, not a `byte` array (`byte[]`).

```
control ctrl = new control();
byte[] bytes = structtobyte(ctrl);
```

Comment: control cnt;structtobyte(cnt); I`m passing it my edited cnt struct, it is filled with data.

Comment: You have not provided a stack trace/exception location but the exception you get is most likely from `Marshal.SizeOf`. The exception message clearly states that you are supplying a byte array. Hence my answer.