# Max byte calculated by System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf()

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on an issue that throws out of memory exception. I tried to use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf()` to know the size of culprit data type but it gave me exceptio saying :

```
$exception
{"Type 'System.String' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed."}
System.ArgumentException
```

code is :

```
 var size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(xmlDataSet.GetXml());
```

any idea guys?

Comment: Is the answer to this question going to solve your original problem?

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf` is only relevant if you're actually attempting to marshal the data into unmanaged memory - is that your intention? If not, then its irrelevant.

Comment: Have you considered using some kind of memory profiler instead? I'm for example using dotMemory (both personally and at work), and can really recommend it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399332/struct-marshal-in-c-sharp ?

Answer (score 0):

As the the damien_the_unbeliever pointed out the marshaling work as a bridge between the `managed and unmanaged` world. String does not exists in the unmanaged world  and it should be marshaled as one of the folowing unmanaged system  type

```
UnmanagedType.BStr
UnmanagedType.LPStr
UnmanagedType.LPTStr
UnmanagedType.LPWStr
```

if you really whant to check the size I suggest to try the following

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test xmlStruct;
        xmlStruct.xmlFile = "bla blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah";
        xmlStruct.number = 0;

        var size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(xmlStruct);
        Console.WriteLine(size);

    }

}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]  
struct Test
{

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] 
   public String xmlFile;

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
   public int number; 
}

**Note**
```

that this will give you a size of a pointer which is 8 byte which is the value of 2 pointers. 
if you want to  compute the size please follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/y3ybkfb3)